# Azure Devops Build - Want to fail when specific nuget package version does not exist

Tags: azure-devops, nuget

we use Azure Devops for our builds. We have various nuget packages for our solution.  Currently, when a version that we specify doesn't exist, the nuget restore just pulls the next existing version, but we would like to make it so that the build fails and does not pull the next existing version.

For example, we specify v1.0, if it doesn't exist, we'd like the whole build to fail instead of pulling v1.1.  Is there a way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the version of the package you reference in the square brackets in your csproj file, like this:

```
<PackageReference Include="ExamplePackage" Version="[1.0]" />
```

See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#version-ranges) for more details and other options.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer says, you can use NuGet's syntax for an exact version match, rather than "greater than or equal to". [This is documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#version-ranges). This only works for packages included directly in your project. It doesn't work for transitive dependencies.

Another option, depending on your use-case, is to notice that NuGet gives you a warning when the requested version doesn't exist and it uses a higher version instead. Then, tell NuGet to treat this warning as an error:

```xml
<WarningsAsErrors>$(WarningsAsErrors);NU1603</WarningsAsErrors>
```

An advantage of this is you can put it in a `Directory.Build.props` in your repo root, and all projects in the solution will get this behavior.

This will work for transitive dependencies as well. But for this reason if there's a package that you do not control who ends up declaring a dependency that does not exist, then the best option is probably to declare that missing dependency as a direct package reference, and change the version to one that exists (NuGet's "nearest-wins" rule).  Or, maybe adding a package-specific NoWarn might work:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.0" NoWarn="NU1603" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate it.